# jquery with typescript: Cannot find name 'JQuery'

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I use jquery in angular and add type definition on jquery element, I wonder what the type of jquery element?

```
import {JQuery} from 'jquery';    
const filterPathItems: JQuery = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.filter-path-item');
```

Erorr is

> Cannot find name 'JQuery'.

Not use `any` definition cause our project are not allowed to use `any` type...

Comment: `declare var jQuery:any;`

Comment: Seems like the name to import is `$` or `jQuery` instead of `JQuery`.

Comment: Yes , it should be like this import { $ } from '../jquery-v.1.1';

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the version. Looking at the [most current definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts):

```
declare module 'jquery' {
    export = jQuery;
}

declare module 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim' {
    export = jQuery;
}

declare const jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

You can either import `jQuery` (lowercase `j`) or use the global variables `$` or `jQuery` without module imports.